# Specify git commands in Jenkins Git plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, ant, jenkins-github-plugin

I have written following ant target to fetch code from a GitHub repository.

```
<target name="fetch" description="Fetching the Source Code">
  <echo message="-------------------------------------------------------------"/>
  <echo message="Fetching Latest from ${build.git.organization}/${build.git.repository} ${build.git.branch}"/>  
  <echo message="-------------------------------------------------------------"/>
  <exec executable="git" dir="${build.source.location}\${build.git.repository}" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="fetch ${build.git.organization}/${build.git.repository} ${build.git.branch}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

The target works fine when I run it from the command prompt. However, when I try to run it from Jenkins, it fails with the following error:

> BUILD FAILED C:\Users\PJai12\test\build.xml:66: Execute failed:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": CreateProcess error=2,
>   The system cannot find the file specified     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:629)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:670)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:496)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)

In order to make sure that the Jenkins is properly configured with git path and ssh credentails, I created anothe job. The job just poll scm from the same repository through Jenkins GitHub plugin. It worked fine.

Here is the GIT configuration in Jenkins: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSd67.jpg

Comment: First, you cannot modify git commands flow much without forking plugin you're using. Second, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec. You might achieve that with more complicated setup (i.e. using scripted pipelines or external scripts to call git subcommands) to alter basic Jenkins job routine

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The executable should have a complete path of Git executable.

```
<exec executable="PATH_TO_GIT_EXE" dir="${build.source.location}\${build.git.repository}" failonerror="true">
```