# Git | Jenkins | Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-github-plugin

We have a common LDAP account/user. We plan to use this user to configure Jenkins for our team.

1. I logged in to the machine/VM using my login and installed Jenkins.
2. Then I generated ssh keys from my account only but the email id I provided while generating ssh keys was the common user.
3. Then I added the public ssh key to the GitHub (in Github I logged in using common user).
4. Added the private key to Jenkins SSH credential plugin.
5. Created a job that does poll SCM and it worked fine.
6. I need to execute some git commands (i.e pull, checkout, tag etc...). Therefore, I'm writing ant scripts to achieve this.
7. When I execute the GIT ant target [1] through Jenkins, I get the following error:

> fetch:
>   [echo] ---------------------------------------------------------
>
> [echo] Fetching Latest from git@github.XYZ.com:XYZ/ABC master
>
> [echo] ---------------------------------------------------------
>
> [exec] git@github.XYZ.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>
> [exec] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> [exec]
>
> [exec] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>
> [exec] and the repository exists.

Do I have to log in to the VM using common account/user and generate the ssh keys and then use those keys? If yes, then how come Point# 5 is working fine? If no, what is wrong I'm doing here?

[1] - [Specify git commands in Jenkins Git plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54300414/specify-git-commands-in-jenkins-git-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins will use its private key associated with the job to read the remote repo.

But: the script executed within the job itself will use the default SSH key found in the user running Jenkins itself: ~user/.ssh/id_rsa

Make sure the default private key is the one you need for that job (or you can set one through `~/.ssh/config`): the point being, this is no longer related to the Jenkins SSH Credential plugin.